how to implement JsonConverter in dart flutter?
I am trying make custom JsonConverter using JsonConverter in dart but I am not able to use it with error message saying "Classes can only extend other classes."
Do I need to import something to use JsonConverter? or what am I missing?
class MyJsonConverter extends JsonConverter<Value, JSON> {
  // TODO
}

@JsonSerializable()
@MyJsonConverter()
class Example {
  final Value property;
}


To use JsonConverter, you need to add the “json_annotation” library to your project, then import it into your file.
Using Flutter
flutter pub add json_annotation

Using Dart
dart pub add json_annotation

Then, you import the library into your file :
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

